# How to use parse server and AWS together in order for HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: ios, html, amazon-web-services, parse-server, http-live-streaming

I am trying to build a ios app to live stream videos. So far I have been using parse.com and already built the authentication and other basic things for app. Now, I am trying to use AWS Cloudfronts to store videos.

As per the resources I found, we could use them together with webhooks but this is not available in parse-server(open source). So, how can it be done now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: parse.com still available ? or you have clone it on your server ?

Comment: I have cloned it in my aws ec2...

Comment: for that you have to contact AWS support as nothing extra set up for this video streaming so.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what you said could you elaborate..

Comment: From where you are taking the live stream video URL? i am asking because i assume you would like to keep this URL in the DB also..

Comment: @RanHassid I am storing video URL in Parse Server and storing the video in AWS S3 Bucket.

Comment: So you don't need WebHooks you can use PFFile together with AWS S3 adapter in order to get the URL of your file and stream it in your client side

Comment: @RanHassid I also have a media server and that media server can manage the media. That server is supposed to work together with the AWS S3 adapter if I am not wrong.